# How to generate permutations of sublists of a list?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to generate permutations of the list in a specialized way: divide the list into blocks containing 2 consecutive elements: (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) and then permute each block independently.

I want the result to look like this:

```
y=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,6,5],[1,2,4,3,5,6],[1,2,4,3,6,5],[2,1,3,4,5,6],[2,1,3,4,6,5],[2,1,4,3,5,6],[2,1,4,3,6,5]].
```

So basically all possible permutations, except permutations are allowed only on each block.

Is there any natural python way of doing this? Writing the code myself results in fairly complicated lines of codes.

Comment: this is quite an specific thing, you'll have to code it yourself

Comment: What if there are an odd number of elements in the given list?

Comment: [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: @md2perpe I assume that no such cases arise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use various functions from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```py
import itertools as it

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 2
assert len(x) % n == 0

chunks = zip(*it.repeat(iter(x), n))
y = it.product(*(it.permutations(c) for c in chunks))
y = [list(it.chain.from_iterable(z)) for z in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using `itertools`:

```py
def pair_list(values):
    if len(values) % 2 == 1:
        raise ValueError("List must have even length")

    return [(values[2*i], values[2*i+1]) for i in range(len(values) // 2)]


def unpair_list(paired_list):
    return [value for pair in paired_list for value in pair]


def pair_permutations(paired_values):
    if not paired_values:
        yield []
        return

    (x, y) = paired_values[0]
    rest = paired_values[1:]

    for rest_permutations in pair_permutations(rest):
        yield [(x, y), *rest_permutations]
        yield [(y, x), *rest_permutations]


def solution(values):
    paired_values = pair_list(values)
    permutations = pair_permutations(paired_values)
    return list(map(unpair_list, permutations))


def main():
    print(solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```